# How to send generic T to another thread?

Tags: multithreading, generics, rust, traits, parametric-polymorphism

How to send generic `T`?

I try to send a generic `T` to another thread but I'm getting:

```
error[E0308]: mismatched types
  --> src/main.rs:23:22
   |
23 |             t1.merge(Element(vec![3]));
   |                      ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ expected associated type, found struct `Element`
   |
   = note: expected associated type `<T as Join>::Item`
                       found struct `Element`
   = help: consider constraining the associated type `<T as Join>::Item` to `Element`
```

Full code:

```rust
trait Join {
    type Item;
    fn merge(&mut self, other: Self::Item);
}

#[derive(Debug, Default)]
struct Element(Vec<u8>);

impl Join for Element {
    type Item = Element;
    fn merge(&mut self, mut other: Self::Item) {
        self.0.append(&mut other.0);
    }
}

fn work<T>()
where
    T: Default + Join + Send + Sync + 'static,
{
    let (sender, receiver) = std::sync::mpsc::channel::<(T)>();
    std::thread::spawn(move || {
        while let (mut t1) = receiver.recv().unwrap() {
            t1.merge(Element(vec![3]));
        }
    });

    loop {
        let mut t1 = T::default();
        sender.send(t1);
        std::thread::sleep(std::time::Duration::from_secs(5));
    }
}

fn main() {
    // works!
    let mut e = Element(vec![1]);
    e.merge(Element(vec![2]));

    // bad!
    work::<Element>();
}
```

[Playground link](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=45590ec0437026784ee34be430dcf814)

Comment: Please put the code inline, not on an external link.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you use generics you let *the caller* decide which types must be used by your generic function.

This line in your example `t1.merge(Element(vec![3]));` is invalid because it assumes `T = Element` but the caller can chose from infinitely many possible types of `T` where `T != Element` which is why the compiler is complaining.

To make your function fully generic you have to do something like add a `Default` bound to `<T as Join>::Item` in the function signature and then change the offending line to `t1.merge(<T as Join>::Item::default());`.

Updated working commented example:

```rust
use std::fmt::Debug;

trait Join {
    type Item;
    fn merge(&mut self, other: Self::Item);
}

#[derive(Debug)]
struct Element(Vec<u8>);

// updated Default impl so we can observe merges
impl Default for Element {
    fn default() -> Self {
        Element(vec![1])
    }
}

impl Join for Element {
    type Item = Element;
    fn merge(&mut self, mut other: Self::Item) {
        self.0.append(&mut other.0);
    }
}

fn work<T>() -> Result<(), Box<dyn std::error::Error>>
where
    T: Default + Join + Send + Sync + Debug + 'static,
    <T as Join>::Item: Default, // added Default bound here
{
    let (sender, receiver) = std::sync::mpsc::channel::<T>();
    std::thread::spawn(move || {
        while let Ok(mut t1) = receiver.recv() {
            // changed this to use Default impl
            t1.merge(<T as Join>::Item::default());

            // prints "Element([1, 1])" three times
            println!("{:?}", t1);
        }
    });

    let mut iterations = 3;
    loop {
        let t1 = T::default();
        sender.send(t1)?;
        std::thread::sleep(std::time::Duration::from_millis(100));
        iterations -= 1;
        if iterations == 0 {
            break;
        }
    }

    Ok(())
}

fn main() -> Result<(), Box<dyn std::error::Error>> {
    // works!
    let mut e = Element(vec![1]);
    e.merge(Element(vec![2]));

    // now also works!
    work::<Element>()?;

    Ok(())
}
```

[playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=5bb9bc2067f1042bae7aa73260e3eb0c)

Comment: Or he could simply specify that `T: Join<Item=Element>` ([playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=f589560d3596ff3aba3ab8fc8bda1d41))